# Problems with LTTng-modules-2.8 on RaspberryPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, lttng

I'm using a RaspberryPi Zero W with Raspbian 4.9.80+ and I'm trying to install LTTng-modules-2.8 but when I type these commands

```
wget http://lttng.org/files/lttng-modules/lttng-modules-latest- 
2.8.tar.bz2 &&
tar -xf lttng-modules-latest-2.8.tar.bz2 &&
cd lttng-modules-2.8.* &&
make &&
sudo make modules_install &&
sudo depmod -a
```

I receive this (after typing the command "make"):

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.9.80+/build M=/home/pi/lttng-modules-2.8.7 
CONFIG_LTTNG=m
 CONFIG_LTTNG_CLOCK_PLUGIN_TEST=m modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.9.80+/build: No such file or directory. Stop.
Makefile:110: receipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I downloaded the modules correctly but it seems that they are not there; how can I solve this problem?

Thanks, Ivan.

Answer (score 0):

You need the kernel headers to build modules, according to raspbian's documentation they are provided by the **raspberrypi-kernel-headers**, you can install it with this command :

```
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

And then run the make commands.

Comment: Hi Michael Jeanson, thank you for your reply; I already have installed the raspberry kernel headers; is there anything else I can do?